# jQuery Mobile grids not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've made a simple page to test jQuery Mobile grids. I just copied/pasted everything from [jQuery Mobile demo website](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/) but nothing seems to work.

The blocks simply does not align properly, [as you can see from this test page i've made](http://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/test.html). If (magically) you see them aligned, [this is a screenshot of what i see](http://www.racebooking.net/images/blocks-not-aligned.jpg).

What's really driving me crazy is that [the same exact code works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcqqLejr/2/)!!!

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

Any idea?

Comment: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, i just realized that! But why? What's happening and never happened in my life is that the "TAB" character, which i use to indent and keep my code clean, is being rendered as &nbsp; Do you know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe, try it without tab. If you want to beautify your code, use some online code beautifiers e.g. http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem!

In [the examples on the jQuery Mobile website](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/) the don't use TABS, but they use spaces, which are converted as `&nbsp;` by the browser and make the last block go down. Therefore, by copying and pasting from their website i got this issue.

Very tricky to find

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved me! It gave me headache... A shame that its still a issue 2018!